$\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{1-x^2}=1$ proof using epsilon-delta
To show $\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{1-x^2}=1$:
For any $\epsilon>0$, $\exists\delta$: $|x-0|<\delta \implies \epsilon>|f(x)-1|$
$|x|<\delta \implies x^2<\delta^2$$\implies$$1-x^2>1-\delta^2\\\sqrt{1-x^2}>\sqrt{1-\delta^2}\\\sqrt{1-x^2}-1>\sqrt{1-\delta^2}-1\\\epsilon>f(x)-1>\sqrt{1-\delta^2}-1\\\epsilon>|f(x)-1|\geq f(x)-1$
This implies that any $\delta$ can be chosen for all $\epsilon$, hence the limit is 1. Is this proof incorrect, why then? How should i approach it instead?

There are several steps to fix in your proof.
First two minor points:

$\delta$ should be chosen $>0$ (you forgot to mention it, and if $\delta<0$ then "$|x-0|<\delta \implies \epsilon>|f(x)-1|$" is vacuously true), but also $\le1$, for $1-\delta^2$ to have a real square root;
"any δ can be chosen for all ϵ" doesn't mean what you have in mind and previously wrote formally, namely: "for every ϵ, some δ can be chosen".

Now the two crucial points (imo):

in $\sqrt{1-x^2}-1>\sqrt{1-\delta^2}-1$, both sides are $\le0$ hence $<\epsilon$, but their absolute values are in the reverse order, which is more helpful;
even if you had succeded in proving $|x|<\delta\implies|f(x)-1|\color{red}>$ something (depending on $\delta$), which is actually impossible, this wouldn't have helped to find some $\delta\in(0,1]$ such that $|x|<\delta\implies|f(x)-1|\color{red}<\epsilon$. What you need instead is: $$|x|<\delta\implies|f(x)-1|{\bf\color{green}<}\text{ something}$$
where this "something" depends on $\delta$, and can be made as small as we want by taking $\delta$ sufficiently small.

Now your proof can be corrected as follows:
For any $\delta\in(0,1]$,
$$\begin{align}|x|<\delta&\implies x^2<\delta^2\\&\implies1-x^2>1-\delta^2\\&\implies\sqrt{1-x^2}>\sqrt{1-\delta^2}\\&\implies|f(x)-1|=1-\sqrt{1-x^2}<1-\sqrt{1-\delta^2}\end{align}$$
hence in order to get $|x|<\delta\implies|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$, it is sufficient to choose $\delta\in(0,1]$ such that $1-\sqrt{1-\delta^2}<\epsilon$.

If $\epsilon>1$, any $\delta\in(0,1]$ will do.
If $0<\epsilon\le1$, what we want is $1-\delta^2>(1-\epsilon)^2$ i.e. $\delta^2<1-(1-\epsilon)^2=2\epsilon-\epsilon^2$. Since $0<2\epsilon-\epsilon^2\le1$, any $\delta\in(0,\sqrt{2\epsilon-\epsilon^2})$ will do.

